# Converters between formats in different journals

Tags: document-classes, journal-publishing

Often, a paper is submitted to a journal, rejected, then sent to a different journal. Each journal has different style guides. In theory, changing the style should be as easy as changing the document class. But in practice, this is never that easy. Each journal has several peculiarities such as: how exactly the author names are specified, how keywords are specified, whether "cite" or "citep" or "citeN" should be used for citations, etc.   After doing such technical changes manually several times, I wonder: are there any automatic converters that take a LaTeX file in e.g. the format of e.g. ACM/Springer/Elsevier, and converts it to the format required by a different publisher?

Comment: No, and due to the flexibility of latex it is imho impossible.

Comment: @Erel you should give a bounty for somebody making a converter to answer your question. As Ulrike pointed out is such a code is an amazing work. Blessings! (and I hope you find one).

Comment: I am surprised. Apparently, the changes look just like a sequence of regular expression replacement (e.g, replacing "\cite" with "\citeN" and then "\citep" with "\cite", etc.)

Comment: Don't format the article for the journal prior to submission. Format it for the journal if they accept it. At least, that's how people do it in my discipline. (Except most people say 'Oh, yeah. I used to do that but then I realised the referees don't care so long as it is clear etc.') In fact, most journals don't allow you to submit fully formatted stuff: the authors' names, affiliations etc., in particular, ought not be included at the submission stage. (Unless the journal is really very badly behind the times.)

Comment: This is provably impossible

Comment: @percusse What is the proof? And why is it more difficult than other types of conversions that are possible (at least approximately), such as LaTeX to HTML : http://latex2html.org/node1.html#SECTION00011000000000000000 ?

Comment: Because journal templates are not standard. You'll only loose time.

Comment: Although the question is interesting, I concur with percusse: there is no efficient solution, you'll have to do it by hand. Editor's classes are undocumented, sometimes buggy, and they use different packages, in different orders, with sometimes hacks on top of it.

Comment: For this exact reason, I frequently define my own new commands (not renewcommand) to process certain tasks like glossary insertions, bib citations, title page objects like authors etc.  This provides me a simple interface layer to reprogram for the journals requirements without having to change individual instances in the documents itself. This isn't always super successful because there are times where you aren't using commands exclusively (particularly in glossary and bib), but I find that needing them unique doesn't violate formatting guidelines because they were used for a unique scenario.

Comment: @EngBIRD they'll balk at "non-standard" (i.e., not their own) definitions. Some forbid using your own macros.